# Bind to property of DataContext of another user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

I have Player inside data context of user control. I want to Bind `ListView` from main window to property of Player : `Tracks`.

**MainWindow:**

```
<Window 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PlayerApp"
    xmlns:player="clr-namespace:Player"
    ... >

<local:PlayerControl x:Name="PlayerControl" />

<ListBox x:Name="TrackList"
         ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.(player:Player.Tracks) , <!--error here-->
                               Source={x:Reference PlayerControl} , 
                               Mode=OneWay}" 
         SelectedIndex="{Binding DataContext.(player:Player.SelectedTrack) , <!--no error-->
                                 Source={x:Reference PlayerControl}}" 
         SelectionMode="Single"/>
```

**UserControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="PlayerApp.PlayerControl" ... >
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <player:Player x:Name="MyPlayer"/> <!--player is created here-->
    </UserControl.DataContext>
```

These are the properties inside `Player` class.

```
public ObservableCollection<Track> Tracks { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Track>();
public int SelectedTrack { get; set; }
```

The binding does work fine only at **runtime**. I.e in designer part I'm getting

> Ivalid Markup : Check the Error List for more information

Therefore I cant see MainWindow in designer. I get this error in XAML.

> The member "Tracks" is not recognized or is not accessible

The program compiles fine. Runs fine, even binding works fine but this error is stuck.

I tried restart `.net`. clean solution. close all windows and open it again. but error is there. is this bug or something i did wrong? what could be the cause?

Is there any other way to bind like this without getting error?

Comment: Works for me, without any design-time error. What does `Track` look like?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I found the error. it was due to having Track in another assembly and not referencing it. Its however still interesting that program compiled and worked fine without referencing assembly. wpf binding still looks magic to me @PetterHesselberg

Comment: Indeed. :-) (And you're welcome.)